# For ray tracing refractions/reflections, shouldn't Transmittance+Reflectance = 1?

Tags: graphics, physics, raytracing

In this code mind article, http://www.codermind.com/articles/Raytracer-in-C++-Depth-of-field-Fresnel-blobs.html, the part about reflection/refraction has a few cases it checks for whether to transmit or reflect a ray.

It says for rand_num in range 0 to 1:

```
if(rand_num<=reflectance){
    //reflect a ray
}else if(rand_num<=reflectance+transmittance){
    //transmit a ray through surface
}else{
    //diffuse calculation
}
```

I was under the impression that reflectance+transmittance = 1, so that else statement would be usesless. What should transmittance be if not 1-reflectance?

Comment: There are four things that happen to incoming light: 1) Directed reflection 2) diffuse reflection 3) absorption 4) transmittance

Comment: So I would imagine that direction reflection would be the case reflectance = 1.0f and transmit = 0.0f. Then transmittance would be the case transmit = 1.0f and reflectance = 0.0f. So what are the other two cases?

Comment: The link to codermind no longer works. I wonder what happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

In such a simple model there are four things that happen to incoming light: 1) Directed reflection 2) diffuse reflection 3) absorption 4) transmittance

A few (idealized) examples:

- Mirror: only directed reflection
- White: only diffuse reflection
- Black: only absorption
- Anti-reflection glass: only transmittance

Absorption is handled implicitly by setting the sum of the three coefficients to a value smaller than one.

In practice there are some additional effects, like reflection only which only goes approximately in the ideal direction with the mean deviation depending on material, material that emits light by itself, unusual reflection effects that are directional or change the color...

Answer (score 0):

It basically gives the answer in the comment in the code:

A ray get transmitted, reflected or diffusely reflected. Physically the later two are the same, but in raytracing the two are handle differently.

The first produces highlights and actual reflections like in a mirror, while the diffuse part is important for surfaces like rubber that look very different from mirrors.

Comment: I believe that. My question is that if rand_num is in the range 0 to 1, and reflect+transmit = 1 always, then that else statement will never be called. Rand_num has to be less than or equal to reflect+transmit.

Comment: "Reflectance" here refers specifically to specular (mirror-like) reflection.

Comment: So when you say reflectance, are you referring to a coefficient in the brdf of the surface. Like someone might say that any reflected ray needs to be multiplied by this "reflectance" constant. But this is different from the calculated reflectance from the fresnel equations?